# Convert textures to ETC1 in a batch using etcpack

Tags: opengl-es, batch-file, dos

I have to convert my game's texture files to ETC (Ericsson Texture Compression) format,
using the command line conversion

```
etcpack img.jpg new-img.jpg
```

I have 100+ files in a the folder and using the etcpack tool on each file from command line is a pain.

Can i write a dos script or batch file to do that and how should i do it for all files in my current folder and subfolders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the command line, without using a script:

```
for /r %F in (*.jpg) do etcpack "%F" "new-%f"
```

You shouldn't run the above command twice, else it will try to convert the already converted "new-..." files. The following more complex command is safe to run multiple times.

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %F in ('dir /b /s /a-d *.jpg ^| findstr /vlib "new-"') do etcpack "%F" "new-%F"
```

If you want to put either command in a batch script, then change each `%F` into `%%F`.

Comment: @user565223 - That is what the `for /f` and `dir /s` options are for. Have you tried either command? You can put `echo` between `do` and `etcpack` if you want to test first without actually doing anything.